# res.locals y can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: nodejs

Tengo un layout que contiene el `head` de mi html más el `navbar` o barra de navegación: en esta barra de navegación tengo un formulario que tiene una etiqueta `select` y dichas opciones son creadas con una variable que está en `res.locals` con un arreglo que traigo de una tabla en una base de datos mysql, la información la paso con un middleware llamado *control-sesiones* y lo que hace es pasar la información del usuario en cada vista dentro de las rutas `localhost:3000/admin` a través de `res.locals` y entre esa información también paso el arreglo para las opciones de mi `select`.

El problema es el siguiente:
Tengo una url que es `/admin/proximos-eventos`. En esta url todo el layout funciona de maravilla, el `select` de formulario funciona y tiene todas las opciones del arreglo. El problema es cuando trato de realizar otra vista en la url `/admin/proximos-eventos/info/:idEvento` y ahí me salen dos errores: uno es que me dice que las variables que fueron definidas en `res.locals` son indefinidas (variables que funcionan perfectamente en la url anterior, y ya comprobé que el middleware sí se esta ejecutando, e incluso envío un `console.log(res.locals)` y compruebo que las variables contienen toda la información que necesito), el otro error que me sale es que por consola me dice

> error: can't set headers after they are sent

Quiero saber por qué las variables definidas en `res.locals` funcionan perfectamente en una url y en la otra url no funcionan.

Aquí les dejo mi código del middleware *control-sesiones*:

```
module.exports=function (req,res,next) {
if(!req.session.admin.id){
    res.locals = {errorLogin: true, mensajeError: "No puede acceder a esta direccion, antes debe Iniciar Sesion"};
    res.redirect("/index/login-admin");
}
else{
        res.locals = {errorEvento: true, mensajeError: "lo sentimos, hay problemas con la conexion, intenlo mas tarde, si el problema persiste contactenos"};
    
    var q="SELECT id_admin, permisos, habilitado, nombre_admin, correo FROM administradores WHERE id_admin='"+req.session.admin.id+"'";
    conexion.query(q, function(error, usuario, fields){
        if (!!error) {
            console.log("error encontrando la cuenta del usuario");
            console.log(error);
            res.locals = {errorLogin: true, mensajeError: "lo sentimos, hay problemas con la conexion, intenlo mas tarde, si el problema persiste contactenos"};
            res.redirect("/index/login-admin");
            return;
        }
        //console.log(usuario[0]);
            //console.log(res.locals.admin);
        q="SELECT id_escenario, nombre FROM escenarios ORDER BY nombre ASC";
        conexion.query(q,function(error4, rowsEscenarios, fields3){
            if (!!error4) {
                console.log("error en la consulta 4");
                return;
            }
            //console.log(rowsEscenarios);
                //console.log(res.locals.escenarios);
            q="SELECT id_deporte, deporte FROM deportes ORDER BY deporte ASC";
            conexion.query(q,function(error5, rowsIdDeportes, fields3){
                if (!!error5) {
                    console.log("error en la consulta 5");
                    return;
                }
                //console.log(rowsIdDeportes);
                    //console.log(res.locals.idDeportes);
                q="SELECT * FROM categoria_edad";
                conexion.query(q,function(error6, rowsCategoriaEdad, fields3){
                    if (!!error6) {
                        console.log("error en la consulta 6");
                        return;
                    }
                    //console.log(rowsCategoriaEdad);
                    console.log("middleware control-sesiones");
                    res.locals = {admin: usuario[0], escenarios: rowsEscenarios, idDeportes: rowsIdDeportes, categoriaEdad: rowsCategoriaEdad};
                    console.log(res.locals);
                });
            });
        });
    });

  }
  next();
}
```

El siguiente es el código jade del layout que utilizo en todas las url de `/admin`:

```
.item_form.col-xs-12.col-md-6.col-sm-6
            label.l-t-d.col-xs-12(for="deporte") Deporte o Diciplina
            select#deporte.col-xs-12(name="deporte" form="form-nuevo-evento" -required)
                option seleccione un deporte
                - console.log(admin + " proband");
                each deporte in idDeportes
                    option(value="#{deporte.id_deporte}")=deporte.deporte

        .item_form.col-xs-12.col-sm-6
            label.l-t-d.col-xs-12(for="categoria-edad") Categoria Edad
            select#categoria-edad.col-xs-12(name="categoria_edad" form="form-nuevo-evento" -required)
                option Selecione una  
                for categoria in categoriaEdad
                    option(value="#{categoria.id_categoria_edad}")=categoria.nombre_categoria_edad             



   
        .item_form.col-xs-12
            label.l-t-d.col-xs-12(for="escenario") Escenario
            select#escenario.col-xs-12(name="escenario" form="form-nuevo-evento" required)
                option seleccione una esecenario
                for escenario in escenarios
                    option(value="#{escenario.id_escenario}")=escenario.nombre
```

Estos son la información y los errores que salen por consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que el `next()` esta fuera del callback del query. Por ende, cuando termina el query el `next()` ya se ejecuto, entones estarías haciendo un `res.locals = ...` cuando en realidad el middleware ya se termino de ejecutar, y si para ese momento, el endpoint realizo el `res.send()`, te va tirar que no podes modificar el `res` una vez que el `res.send()` ya se realizo.

Si lo pensas bien el error significa que "No podemos modificar la respuesta una vez que la respueta ya se envio". Por ende, te esta diciendo que ya enviaste la respuesta al navegador / cliente, y todavía estas intentando modificar la respuesta.

Solución: Mete el next() dentro del callback del query en los lugares que corresponda:

```
module.exports=function (req,res,next) {

    if(!req.session.admin.id){
        res.locals = {errorLogin: true, mensajeError: "No puede acceder a esta direccion, antes debe Iniciar Sesion"};
        // Usa el return, así no ejecuta el else y no hace falta tampoco
        return res.redirect("/index/login-admin");
    }


    res.locals = {errorEvento: true, mensajeError: "lo sentimos, hay problemas con la conexion, intenlo mas tarde, si el problema persiste contactenos"};

    var q="SELECT id_admin, permisos, habilitado, nombre_admin, correo FROM administradores WHERE id_admin='"+req.session.admin.id+"'";

    conexion.query(q, function(error, usuario, fields){

        if (!!error) {
            console.log("error encontrando la cuenta del usuario");
            console.log(error);
            res.locals = {errorLogin: true, mensajeError: "lo sentimos, hay problemas con la conexion, intenlo mas tarde, si el problema persiste contactenos"};
            res.redirect("/index/login-admin");
            return;
        }

        q="SELECT id_escenario, nombre FROM escenarios ORDER BY nombre ASC";

        conexion.query(q,function(error4, rowsEscenarios, fields3){
            if (!!error4) {
                console.log("error en la consulta 4");
                // Que continue el request
                next();
                return;
            }


            q="SELECT id_deporte, deporte FROM deportes ORDER BY deporte ASC";
            conexion.query(q,function(error5, rowsIdDeportes, fields3){
                if (!!error5) {
                    console.log("error en la consulta 5");
                    // Que continue el request
                    next();
                    return;
                }

                q="SELECT * FROM categoria_edad";
                conexion.query(q,function(error6, rowsCategoriaEdad, fields3){
                    if (!!error6) {
                        console.log("error en la consulta 6");
                        // Que continue el request
                        next();
                        return;
                    }

                    //console.log(rowsCategoriaEdad);
                    console.log("middleware control-sesiones");
                    res.locals = {admin: usuario[0], escenarios: rowsEscenarios, idDeportes: rowsIdDeportes, categoriaEdad: rowsCategoriaEdad};
                    console.log(res.locals);

                    // Que continue el request
                    next();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Si podes intenta emprolijar un poco mas el código, y no usar numeros en las variables. Intenta no tener [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).